# In python, is it possible to get an object without name from another module?

Tags: python

I want to get all object generated from another module, even the object do not have a name or reference, is it possible? For example:

in module1.py, there's only one line code:

```
MyClass()
```

in module2.py:

```
module1 = __import__("module1")
# print sth of MyClass from module1
```

Comment: If the object has no name or other reference, it's garbage, and will be cleaned up by the garbage collector—immediately in CPython, or very soon in PyPy or Jython. So you can't access it.

Comment: The exception is objects that "register" a reference to themselves somewhere when created. If that's the case for `MyClass`, you'll have to look at the documentation or source to `MyClass` to see where and how it does that, and access it through whatever kind of registry it uses. But that is an uncommon case. More likely, the object just no longer exists for you to access.

Comment: And if you've written `module1.py` yourself: why did you do that `MyClass()` in the first place? Was it for the side-effects of the initializer? Or… some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is generally impossible.

An object that has no name or other reference is garbage. That's the technical meaning of the term "garbage". In CPython (the Python implementation you're probably using if you don't know which one you're using), garbage is collected immediately—as soon as that `MyClass()` statement ends, the instance gets destroyed.

So, you can't access the object, because it doesn't exist.

In some other Python implementations, the object may not be destroyed until the next garbage collection cycle, but that's going to be pretty soon, and it's not deterministic exactly when—and you still have no way to get at it before it's destroyed. So it might as well not exist, even if it hasn't actually been finalized yet.

---

Now, "generally" means there are some exceptions. They're not common, but they do exist.

For example, imagine a class like this:

```
class MyClass:
    _instances = []
    def __init__(self):
        MyClass._instances.append(self)
```

Now, when you do `MyClass()`, there actually *is* a reference to that instance, so it's not garbage. And, if you know where it is (which you'd presumably find in the documentation, or in the source code), you can access it as `MyClass._instances[-1]`. But it's unlikely that an arbitrary class `MyClass` does anything like this.

---

OK, I lied. There is sort of a way to do this, but (a) it’s cheating, and (b) it’s almost certainly a terrible idea that has no valid use cases you’ll ever think of. But just for fun, here’s how you could do this.

You need to write an import hook, and make sure it gets installed before the first time you import the module. Then you can do almost anything you want. The simplest idea I can think of is transforming the AST to turn every expression statement (or maybe just every expression statement at the top level) into an assignment statement that assigns to a hidden variable. You can even make the variable name an invalid identifier, so it'll be safe to run on any legal module no matter what's in the global namespace. Then you can access the first object created and abandoned by the module as something like `module.globals()['.0']`.